# Serialize BigDecimal attribute from a webservice to have a scale of 2

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

The consumer of the SpringBoot webservice needs to receive a response JSON representing an object with multiple properties, one which represents tax with a BigDecimal type. The current implementation returns a value of

```
{
...
tax: 2.2
...
}
```

but the consumer wants the value to be represented like this:

```
{
...
tax: 2.20
...
}
```

Is there a way to do this serialization of the value, without making it a String in the JSON response?

#### BEFORE EDIT

I have tried creating a custom Deserializer like so:

```
public class BigDecimal2JsonDeserializer extends NumberDeserializers.BigDecimalDeserializer {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        BigDecimal value = super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        value = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
        return value;
    }
}
```

and then implement it like so:

```
public class ResponseObjectDto {
@JsonDeserialize(using = BigDecimal2JsonDeserializer.class)
private BigDecimal tax;
}
```

but it was unsuccessfull.

#### AFTER EDIT

I have also tried using a serializer but i haven't found a way to output a numeric value in the JSON, with the correct scale of 2.20

**Note**: yes, i'm aware that 2.2 = 2.20 and that it will be read correctly by the deserializer, it's just what the consumer asked me to implement

Comment: You may have to write another serializer that returns formatted String. Then use `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00");
String tax = df.format(value);`

Comment: I have also tried using a serializer (which btw, from what i can see now, i have made a confusion between serializing and deserializing). My problem right now is that i need to send a JSON response body, and the tax value should be numeric in the JSON, while keeping the scale format of 2.20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you create a custom serializer extending the `StdSerializer` class and include in its `serialize` method the [`BigDecimal#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) method:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<BigDecimal> {

    public CustomSerializer() {
        super(BigDecimal.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        BigDecimal value = t.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        jg.writeNumber(value);
    }
}
```

Then you can annotate the `BigDecimal` field with the [`JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annotation obtaining the expected result:

```
public class ResponseObjectDto {

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal tax;
}
```

Comment: After some errors and multiple stack pages, your solution with StdSerializer did the job. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DjWarWick Glad to have helped :-)